# Get Values from specified id selected in dropdown from database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to read values from dropdown list and display into few textboxes. using c# and MySQL as db.

I got three tables: Products, Cars, Colors.
got one drop down list, and 3 textboxes.

I don`t know how to list products into dropdown, and after selecting a product to display specified "property" in each textbox .

Selecting product 1  (dropdown) -> Displaying BMW ( 1st textbox) green (second txtbox).

every product got static "Car" and "Color" . the property of products never change. they are unique.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this example

```
Table 1 Product
id|name
--------
1 | Car
2 | car


Table 2 Type
id|model
--------
1 | BMW
2 | Mercedes

Table 2 Color
id|car_color
------------
1 | Green
2 | Yellow
```

Helper class

```
class MySQLClass : IDisposable
{
    // Connection string need to be replaced for secure purpuose
    private static string connString = @"Server=xxxx;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxxx;database=xxxxxx";
    /// <summary>
    /// OdbcConnection : This is the connection
    /// </summary>
    SqlConnection oConnection;
    /// <summary>
    /// OdbcCommand : This is the command
    /// </summary>
    SqlCommand oCommand;
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor: This is the constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DataSourceName">string: This is the data source name</param>
    public MySQLClass()
    {
        //Instantiate the connection
        oConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            //Open the connection
            oConnection.Open();
            //Notify the user that the connection is opened
            //Console.WriteLine("The connection is established with the database");
        }
        catch (OdbcException caught)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(caught.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// void: It is used to close the connection if you work within disconnected
    /// mode
    /// </summary>
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        oConnection.Close();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// OdbcCommand: This function returns a valid odbc connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Query">string: This is the MySQL query</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public SqlCommand GetCommand(string Query)
    {
        oCommand = new SqlCommand();
        oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
        oCommand.CommandText = Query;
        return oCommand;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// void: This method close the actual connection
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        oConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (MySQLClass o = new MySQLClass())
{
    string sql = @"
        SELECT Product.id, Product.name, Type.model, Color.car_color FROM Product 
        INNER JOIN Type ON Product.id = Type.id 
            INNER JOIN Color ON Type.id = Color.id;

    ";
    SqlCommand oCommand = o.GetCommand(sql);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oCommand);
    adapter.Fill(dt);


    // ddList is your dropDownList
    ddList.DataSource = dt;
    ddList.DataTextField = "name";
    ddList.DataValueField = "id";
    ddList.DataBind();
}
```

then on your evet use every things you need.